# traitCollection.preferredContentSizeCategory.isAccessibilityCategory for iOS 10

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, cocoa-touch, uitraitcollection

The following code works great on iOS11 to detect if the user has set LARGE FONT in their accessibility settings.

However, I need to support this in iOS10 as well. How can I accomplish this?

Right now the code looks like this:

```
if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
    if traitCollection.preferredContentSizeCategory.isAccessibilityCategory {
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    } else {
        return someSpecificHeight
    }
} else {
    // how to detect is isAccessibilityCategory on non-iOS11 devices?
    // is there some ugly fallback I don't know about?
}
```

Comment: If your labels don't have a height constraint and the constraints in your cell are correctly setup, your labels will expand to fit the size of the text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, based on @Jefflovejapan's answer, it looks like I can do this:

```
 let sizeCategory = traitCollection.preferredContentSizeCategory

        if sizeCategory == .accessibilityMedium
     || sizeCategory == .accessibilityLarge
     || sizeCategory == .accessibilityExtraLarge
     || sizeCategory == .accessibilityExtraExtraLarge
     || sizeCategory == .accessibilityExtraExtraExtraLarge {
            return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
        } else {
            return someSpecificHeight
        }
```

Ugly, but I think it does the trick..

I have to do all the `==` comparisons, because that seems like the only supported operator in iOS10 (all the other ones apparently are added in iOS11)

Comment: The sizeCategory starting with .accessibilityMedium and above all appear to cause standard table cells with detailTextLabel on RHS of cell to add a line break and put the detailTextLabel below main label instead. UITableViewAutomaticDimension does correctly return taller cell heights when this happens, but the problem I was encountering was that it seems to return a minimum of 44px regardless of having smaller labels (without accessibility causing line break). Hence I was able to use above code to set "someSpecificHeight" to my normal 30px cell size, and then all worked as intended.

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on Jeff's answer. I found it cleaner to add an extension to UITraitCollection. Hope this helps for any iOS dev still having to develop for iOS 10 (sad times).

```
extension UITraitCollection {
    var isAccessibleCategory: Bool {
        if #available(iOS 11, *) {
            return preferredContentSizeCategory.isAccessibilityCategory
        } else {
            switch preferredContentSizeCategory {
            case .accessibilityExtraExtraExtraLarge,
                 .accessibilityExtraExtraLarge,
                 .accessibilityExtraLarge,
                 .accessibilityLarge,
                 .accessibilityMedium:
                return true
            default:
                return false
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Can then be used like this

```
return traitCollection.isAccessibleCategory ? UITableView.automaticDimension : someSpecificHeight
```

Answer (score 1):

It [looks like](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicontentsizecategory) `.accessibilityMedium` is the next size up from `.extraExtraExtraLarge`, so maybe that could be your threshold.

Comment: Thanks - see answer I just posted. Your comment was very helpful.